# Passing a value to a function using the comma operator?

Tags: c

I am in the process of learning the C Programming Language and currently I am exploring the comma operator. I feel that I am slowly wrapping my mind around this operator. I found a good discussion on this operator here:

[What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

I also found several examples on how this operator can be used:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i;
   i = (1,2,3);
   printf("i:%d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

And

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() 
{
   int num1 = 1, num2 = 2;
   int res;
   res = (num1, num2);
   printf("%d", res);
}
```

However, I recently ran across an unrelated example where the author happened to be using a comma operator and I am confused as to how it is being used in the example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;   
};

struct date foo(struct date x)
{
    ++x.day;    
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct date today = {10, 11, 2004};
    struct date *newDate, foo();    // comma operator?
    return 0;   
}
```

The thing that is throwing me off is that after the comma operator, it appears that the `foo()` function is being called; however, the `foo()` function is declared to take one parameter, specifically of `struct date`. How is this function being called without any parameters and how does the comma operator fit into this example? Does the comma operator somehow pass the `newDate` pointer into `foo()`? Any insight would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: That's not a comma operator, that's an _init-declarator-list_. May I suggest you get the basics before you start doing fancy (and often obfuscating) things? And that is a strongly deprecated function declarator.

Comment: So the comma in the line, "struct date *newDate, foo();" is not being used a comma operator, but as a function declaration?

Comment: As others wrote: it is two declarations. As a well-meant warning: do not get into the habit of doing this. It obfuscates the code **and** should generate a warning in modern C (i.e. since ca. 18 years). I'd be suspicious about such code. Don't try learning C from snippets you caught here and there, blogs, videos, etc., but get a good C book.

Comment: This code is not deprecated; the above commentor is, as usual, speaking about his own personal style as if it were gospel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no comma operator involved in the line:

```
struct date *newDate, foo();
```

It merely declares `newDate` as pointer to `struct date` and `foo` as function returning `struct date`, that does not specify its arguments (K&R old-style function declaration).

The comma serves in this context as *punctuator*.

The general sentiment is to group function declarations at file scope and do not mix them with objects' declarations.

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz. The comma was throwing me off, and for some reason I thought that it was being used as an operator.